# How to run Interactive broker TWS linux version 10.12.2j from command line supplied by username and password?

Tags: linux, interactive-brokers, tws

I need to run [Interactive Broker Workstation and Gateway TWS software (version 10.12.2j)](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=16044) from linux command line, supplied by username and password. Does anyone know how to do it?

There are few autorunner [scripts](https://github.com/IbcAlpha/IBC) that worked well with previous versions of TWS (901-963) by automating it and even running them headless. However, with the latest version of TWS, it is hard to do.

Answer (score 1):

I created a docker container [here](https://github.com/Jmarks199/ib_docker) that you can check out. I have not tested it in about a year, so this is more for reference only, but it should get you in the right direction. It was working with version 978.